# Windows application using Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, expression-blend

I want to develop a windows based application in silverlight. I went through many articles and every where I found that "Silverlight is for web based application". I don't know whether I am wrong or right, as my superiors told me that in Silverlight5 we can develop Windows based application. Can any body help me to give a clue for how to start. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean a Windows based application which can connect with internet you go for `Out of Browser application` which silverlight supports but if you want simple plain desktop application, there is no point in using Silverlight, WPF would be the right choice in that case.

Look at [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20110315205742/http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/out-of-browser-applications/) article for building an out of browser app using Silverlight.

Silverlight specializes in building rich UI based Web applications and WPF is best for making UI rich applications for Desktop.

Answer (score 4):

You can run silverlight apps "Out Of Browser", its just a setting in the config. Here's a video with more info: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/out-of-browser-experiences/

Answer (score 3):

silverlight is a web-based technology that runs on the client machine.  it is, basically, Microsoft's version of Flash.

Now, that being said, you CAN write silverlight apps that run out of the browser. but, they are not "really" windows apps. silverlight is a sub-set of WPF.  However, you can also make WPF apps that run in a browser.  Confused yet?

The bottom line is that WPF is for desktop apps and is full-featured with access to the machine resources.

while silverlight is a light-weight version of WPF that is intended to be run in a browser, similar to flash.  it does not have all the features of a full desktop application due to security model and that sort of thing.

Both have elements that cross into the domain of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Like all good things, the answer is "it depends on what you're trying to do".  If you want an application that can run inside the browser, outside the browser, plus on Windows and Mac then Silverlight is the answer.  You also get for free/are restricted by a security sandbox; you can get around this sandbox by requiring additional permissions from the user.  If you're trying to do something that requires multiple monitor support, access to COM objects, stroke/pen/stylus input, 3D hardware acceleration, or access to a large local file store then WPF is probably the better answer.  Silverlight out of browser applications also have a nice "phone home" feature that will automatically download updates; WPF requires you to roll this by hand.

Some folks have mention XBAPs (running WPF inside of a browser).  Stay away from this error prone steaming pile of stuff.  It's good for demoware, but is not something which you'd want to support.

Answer (score 0):

You heard right.

This is called ["out of browser"](https://web.archive.org/web/20110315205742/http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/out-of-browser-applications/):

> Silverlight-based applications typically run within Web pages, but you can enable users to install them from the Web and run them outside the browser.